# Programs not detecting DLLs properly

Tags: windows

I have recently decided to start playing some games just to be slapped really hard by Windows. Almost any game I tried to run crashed with error `0xC000007B`.

After doing some research, I ended up reinstalling all the necessary DLLs and stuff, but not even that helped. Afterwards I turned to DependencyWalker, and oh boy what a show that was. Basically EVERY DLL was reported as missing. That obviously does not make sense, but just to make sure, I checked some of those DLLs and I am pretty much sure all of those DLLs are in fact properly installed.

And so here I am. I was not able to find anything on this topic and so I would like to ask for an advice. Truthfully, I have no idea what I should do. It looks almost as if the program could not access C:/Windows or something, so I also tried running the program with administrator privileges, but not even that changed anything.

Side note: I also tried some other programs for the sake of making sure and it turns out that the very same DLL one program can use, the other can not. This is completely beyond me. For anyone asking, the programs in question are Arma 3 and DMC: Devil May Cry, both of them error out, while for example CS:GO works flawlessly and has no errors.

Comment: Take a step back. The output of Dependency Walker is very hard to understand for modern software. It will not help. Also, one does not _reinstall DLLs_. Please describe exactly what you did, which DLLs are supposedly missing and how you procured them. How did you install the games, from Steam? Steam sometimes fails to perform games’ one-time setups.

Comment: @DanielB By reinstalling I just meant replacing the files, I just felt the wording was not quite the best so I used reinstall, my apologies. About DependencyWalker, while yes, it does struggle, it still can provide one with at least an idea of what could be missing. About the missing DLLs - all of them, from user32.dll to kernel32.dll, to anything else. I find it very hard to believe Steam would fail to install everything and DependencyWalker would report everything as missing when another game runs just fine.

Comment: I believe that 0xC000007B is caused by attempting to run a program against the wrong architecture.  Please provide more information.  What CPU?  What version of Windows (32bit 64bit?)

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Youre a godsent, Im running x64, 64bit Windows 10 installation, until now I have been running for example arma3_64.exe, which errored out, but using only arma3.exe ran just fine, however I cant find such an alternative for DMC, so I guess the game is just not compatible.

Comment: This sounds like you have the 32bit version of windows and not the 64bit version.  Don't give up! :)  You can do this!

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I believe this may be because my installation could be corrupt to some extent, nevertheless I reinvestigated DMC in DependencyWalker, manually provided x86 DLLs to the exe and it worked, however for some reason, Arma 3's 64bit exe just flops on my system - yes, I'm sure I have 64bit system and windows installation